# What is wrong with my Mapbox expression with "all" operator?

Tags: javascript, filter, mapbox, geojson

I have a geojson with several polygons. Each polygon has a name. I want to display all polygons except for the "boundingBox". I use the filter in addLayer():

```
"filter": ["all",["==", "$type", "Polygon"],["!=",["string", ['get', 'name'],""], "boundingBox"]]
```

but no polygons show up.

If I do:

```
"filter": ["==", "$type", "Polygon"]
```

all polygons show up.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: `all` -> It will show the polygon when all of the filters evaluates to `true`.  It mean your one of the filter is evaluating to false. - https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a mix of deprecated filter syntax (`$type`) and expression syntax, which is not allowed.

> Expression syntax and the deprecated syntax below cannot be mixed in a single filter definition.
>   https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#other-filter

Try

```
"filter": ["all",["==", ["geometry-type"], "Polygon"],["!=",["string", ['get', 'name'],""], "boundingBox"]]
```